# Assign double value to label in C#

Tags: c#-2.0

How do i assign double value to a string ?

Example :

double a = 5.5,b= 6.0;
double sum = a + b ;

Lable1.Text = sum.ToString();

Result :
11.5

but in label i am getting only 11...how do i display 11.5 in lable ?

Answer (score 8):

```
Label1.Text = sum.ToString("#0.0");
```

Generally speaking, "0" is a zero placeholder and "#" is a digit placeholder. You can find more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx). You can also try

```
Label1.Text = sum.ToString("F1");
```

where 1 stands for one digit after the decimal point.